# Can DOS MZ binaries have VERSIONINFO metadata at all?

Tags: windows, winapi, binary, dos, versioninfo

I was under impression what VERSIONINFO resource is a purely Windows invention, however while reading [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa381058), I stumbled upon `VOS_DOS` possible value of `fileos` parameter of `VERSIONINFO` resource definition statement. Likewise, a binary equivalent, [`VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646997) struct have `dwFileOS` member, which can have `VOS_DOS` value, designating what "*The file was designed for MS-DOS.*" (??).

How can it be? I thought what MZ binary format simply does not have a room for such metadata... Am I missing something, like VERSIONINFO support in the greater MS-DOS versions and some kind of libraries to read it?

Comment: Well ... a file can be both a valid DOS binary and a valid Windows binary.  Normally this is used to give a Windows executable a DOS stub which just prints "run me in Windows" or similar, but I suppose it could be used to give a DOS executable a Windows stub which just prints "run me in DOS".  Such a file could contain a `VERSIONINFO` resource and I suppose `VOS_DOS` would be the logical choice for `fileos`.

Comment: Resources are not necessarily associated with executable files.  It is just a binary format, it can be stored anywhere.  A .res file for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard for resource data for plain MZ files. However, NE and PE files can execute under DOS with a help of a [DOS extender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_extender). I believe Microsoft themselves used [Phar Lap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phar_Lap_%28company%29) in some versions of Visual C so that they could run the same executable in Windows and DOS.

It seems the NE format has also been used [in early versions of MS DOS 4.0](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/?p=1769).